# react-bootstrap change DropdownButton title not by using a state

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i would like to change the `<DropdownButton>` ***title*** when selecting an item.
the thing is, i cant use state cuz, the dropdown title isnt a static "name"
see in example:

```
    this.props.itemToFltr.keys.map((key /* initial name to button */)=>{
         return (
               <DropdownButton id="dropdownBtn" bsSize="xsmall"  title={key} 
                 onSelect={(evt,name)=>{ /* can i change the title from here ? */ } } >

                  {this.props.itemToFltr[key].map((val)=>{
                  return <MenuItem eventKey={val} >{val} </MenuItem>
                })}

               </DropdownButton>
              )
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `this.state`, just remap `itemToFltr` to a new list with the updated key and let react do the work of rendering only the items that  changed.

Comment: how does state fit in the solution u suggested

Answer (score 0):

ok so i have a way  to overcome the problam i just use jquery 
and rund this function on select :

```
onSelect={(evt,name)=>{ $("#dropdownBtn").text(name)  }}
```

thisis my solution for those who cant use state to change the text